# Is there any way to control the video bitrate using FFmpeg Complex Filter other than -b:v?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am trying to compress a part of the video size by reducing the bitrate.I am using FFmpeg to divide the video frame in to tiles and then trying to control the bitrate of only one tile. After reducing the bitrate for one part of the frame i have to stitch back all the tiles into single frame. In this process I am able to split the frame in to tiles and I am successfully controlling the bitrate, but to stitch back all the tiles to frame I have to use hstack filter as chain to the previous function -b:v. As -b:v is not a filter, I am unable to use chaining the filters in ffmpeg commands one after the other.
`ffmpeg -i sam.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=out_w=in_w/2:out_h=in_h/2:x=0:y=0 [one];[0:v]crop=out_w=in_w/2:out_h=in_h/2:x=in_w/2:y=0[two]" [one]

-b:v 200000 [two]hstack=inputs=2[t] -map "[t]" output.mp4` it is throwing error because -b:v is not a filter so I couldn't use ffmpeg chaining. Is there any other way around to do this?

Comment: There is no filter that controls the bitrate. Please clarify your question. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Question edited @LordNeckbeard

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. `-b:v` will control the bitrate (depending on the encoder you choose) regardless if you are filtering or not.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Question updated @Mulvya

Comment: Are you concerned only with the bitrate of that region? Or of the entire frame as well? If the latter, try applying some blur to that region. If no, then you want to effectively define a region of interest. For that, I believe you'll have to use the encoder programmatically and restrict quantization parameters for that region.

Comment: @srujithpoondla There are several questions from users on the x264-devel mailing list who have asked about controlling the quality in a specified area--assuming that's the encoder you want to use. I recommend searching the mailing list for replies (and yes, it will have to be done programmatically).